# Robot_pose_ekf with wheelodometry and IMU

Tags: imu, navigation, odometry, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to use the robot_pose_ekf package fusing the IMU sensor data and the odometry coming from encoders. Is there any documentation or tutorials of settings launch parameters and some nodes examples. Some code examples ?Any helps would be good.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52136/robot_pose_ekf-with-wheelodometry-and-imu/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following link has an example launch file configuration:

> [www.ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf)

The navigation tutorials are a great place to start:

> [www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials)

This tutorial describes how to publish odometry information:

> [www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom)

---

Originally posted by [isura](https://answers.ros.org/users/1583/isura/) with karma: 403 on 2013-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [isura](https://answers.ros.org/users/1583/isura/) on 2013-01-14**:
If this answers your question please mark it as correct (by clicking on the check mark on the left hand side, below the answer heading).

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-01-15**:
But why I need to publish the odometry?? I need to subscribe to odom (nav_msgs/Odometry) . Thats the robot_pose_ekf subscribed topic.

**Comment by [isura](https://answers.ros.org/users/1583/isura/) on 2013-01-15**:
If you have odometry information being published by your robot as a nav_msgs::Odometry, then you do not have to publish it.The robot_pose_ekf node reads odometry messages published as "odom" topic.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-01-15**:
Yes. I already have odometry information published by my robot as nav_msgs::Odometry,